# Submit a New Copy of List Item

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online, custom-list, infopath-rules

I have a SharePoint List that has an InfoPath Form template. I am encountering problem, I have a List Item and when Item is Approved I want to make a copy of it. What I did was when item is approved, a DCR button is visible and it allows the user to edit the document and make some changes. what I want is when the user hits the save button it creates a new item on the List, unfortunately, it just overwrites the list Item that I made and it does not create new List Item.

Answer (score 1):

This is available when using a FORM LIBRARY (I'm currently trying to find a way with LIST ITEMS, but it doesnt look possible). On the Submit Data Connection you specify the Form name. Simply set the Form Name to a field on your form, and update that field to something else before submitting via the Data Connection. You now have two forms in your library, the original and and new one based on the original, all done from an InfoPath Form, rather than SharePoint Workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You talk about a list and an InfoPath form. Is this a list form? Or is this a document library, since you mention a document? Or is this an InfoPath forms library? Please provide these details.

In any case, if you want to duplicate an item, you won't be able to do that from within the current item.

You can easily create a workflow with SharePoint Designer that creates a copy of the item if it is approved.

Comment: I am working with a Sharepoint List @teylyn.. Im sorry for the "document" term. As much as possible, I want to make use of the Infopath form to make a new List item with the values and submit it to List without overwriting the previous List Item. Hope you could help.

Comment: That cannot be done with a list form. You will need a workflow that starts when an item is changed. If the approval field = "Approved" create a new item in the list and populate it with the current item field values.

Comment: I see @teylyn. So I guess, I should make use of Library instead of a List for me to achieve this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, a library won't make a difference. Please read my comments again. Use a WORKFLOW in Sharepoint Designer to duplicate the item. You CAN duplicate a list item. But you CANNOT do that from WITHIN the list form. YOU NEED A WORKFLOW to duplicate the item.